# SDL_PollEvent is causing my window to freeze

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

I was able to find out the **SDL_PollEvent** function was causing my window to be unresponsive/freeze. When i comment it out it works fine, but when i declare it it causes my window to freeze. I'm not sure if it's the functions fault or if something in my code is causing it to act the way it is.

This is the code block that causes the frozen event.

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&m_event))
{
    switch (m_event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call stack:

```
C++ SDL_Project.exe!Screen_namespace::Screen::ProcessEvents() Line 57   

C++  SDL_Project.exe!main() Line 41 

C++ [External Code] kernel32.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll] Unknown
```

**All the files:**

**Main.cpp**

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "Screen.h"


int main()
{


    Screen_namespace::Screen screen;

    if (screen.init() == false)
        std::cout << "Error initializing SDL" << std::endl;


    while (true)
    {

        int elapsed = SDL_GetTicks();
        unsigned char red = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.001) * 128);
        unsigned char green = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.002) * 128);
        unsigned char blue = (1 + sin(elapsed * 0.003) * 128);


        for (int x = 0; x < screen.WINDOW_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < screen.WINDOW_HEIGHT; y++) {
                screen.setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue);
            }
        }

        //screen.setPixel(400, 300, 255, 255, 255);

        //Draw to the screen
        screen.update();


        //Check for messages/events.
        if (screen.ProcessEvents() == false)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    screen.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Screen.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL.h"

namespace Screen_namespace {
    class Screen
    {
    public:
        const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
        const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

        Screen();

        bool init();
        bool ProcessEvents();
        void close();
        void update();
        void setPixel(int x, int y, Uint32 red, Uint32 green, Uint32 blue);

    private:
        SDL_Window* m_window;
        SDL_Renderer* m_renderer;
        SDL_Texture* m_texture;
        Uint32* m_buffer;
        SDL_Event m_event;
    };
}
```

**Screen.cpp**

```
#include "Screen.h"

namespace Screen_namespace {

    Screen::Screen()
        : m_window(NULL), m_renderer(NULL), m_texture(NULL), m_buffer(NULL)
    {
    }

    bool Screen::init()
    {
        const int window_width = 800;
        const int window_height = 600;

        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Particle Fire Explosion", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
        m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        m_buffer = new Uint32[WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT]();

        SDL_memset(m_buffer, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));

        return true;
    }

    void Screen::setPixel(int x, int y, Uint32 red, Uint32 green, Uint32 blue)
    {
        Uint32 color = 0;

        color += red;
        color <<= 8;
        color += green;
        color <<= 8;
        color += blue;
        color <<= 8;
        color += 0xff;

        m_buffer[(y * WINDOW_WIDTH) + x] = color;

    }



    void Screen::update()
    {
        SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, NULL, m_buffer, WINDOW_WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32));
        SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
    }

    bool Screen::ProcessEvents()
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&m_event))
        {
            switch (m_event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void Screen::close()
    {
        delete[] m_buffer;
        SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
        SDL_Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use 2.0.9? I think it has some performance problems on Windows. Try 2.0.8.

Comment: when you say it freezes do you mean that the animation stops or that it won't close and you have to force close it?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "causes my window to freeze". Do you mean the framerate drops?

Also, as a test, can you add a simple `SDL_Delay(1);` in your main loop?

Comment: @Leonid Both. The animation stops and I'm unable to close the window because it's frozen.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yea I use 2.0.9. I'll give 2.0.8 a try.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau By freezing i mean the the animation in the window stops and i'm unable to close the window by clicking "x", so i have to force it to close. I gave SDL_Delay(1) a try and it still persists. Also i don't think it has to do with framerate drops i presume.

Comment: @Antony That's weird. So it looks like the software is stuck in a loop, right? Did you try tracing using a debugger when it happens? When it freezes, what is the call stakc? Can you add that to your question, please?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau Just added the call stack to the question. Also I don't believe it's stuck in a loop because when i try to accumulate a number inside my main loop the number only goes up to 1. For e.g., 
`int num = 0;  num++;  std::cout << num << std::endl;` . The number only goes up to one and stays at one. So i believe some event is being triggered and allowing the program to freeze.

Comment: @Antony Okay, so, really looks like you're stuck in `ProcessEvents()`. Could it be that the event queue is filled with events that are triggered faster than you can process them?

Can you add `std::cout << m_event.type << std::endl;` in your `ProcessEvents()` loop? And maybe a `std::cout << "All events processed" << std::endl;` right after the loop, and then post the results?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau I used pastebin to show you the events the console gave because the list was long, so here [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BXaxkCzd)

Comment: Also I feel like it's necessary to say that my window gets unfrozen when i restart my computer, but then after a few seconds of running it in debug mode it freezes again. Also following up on the previous comment with the events inside the pastebin link. While running my code in debug mode, the while loop/program was working as intended(for like a minute), until i alt tabbed a few times my window froze. Take this as a grain of salt because i'm not sure if this is relevant at all.

Comment: HERE'S THE NEW LINK(with a little more information about what the numbers mean):
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sg8ARAQ4)

Comment: Okay, that is REALLY weird. I don't want to point out the obvious, but that means that you can't process the event queue fast enough because you're receiving mouse motion events. I'm completely at loss. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. Do you have special hardware on your machine? Serial mouse? Touchscreen? Trackpad? Pen tablet?

Comment: ALso, if you download the source code for Lazy Foo's Mouse Events tutorial ( https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/17_mouse_events/index.php ) and compile it, does the tutorial have the same problem?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau No, no extra/special hardware.I tested lazy foo's tutorial and it froze as well. At this point it most likely is a problem with vs itself. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You should post your bug to the SLD2's [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/),

Comment: is this solved ? @r0xptth 
have the same problem